# Is there a way in IE9 on a Virtual Machine to do AD auth in IE9 without the machine being added to the domain but the host machine is?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet-explorer-9, active-directory

I have a virtual machine that is running IE 9 and windows 7 Latest Updates that I want to use to test my intranet site (ASP.Net Application). I can't add the virtual machine to the domain and I don't want to have to type my ad cruds everytime I load the site up. Is there a way for the IE on the virtualbox to Authenticate as my AD Cruds on the host machine so I don't have to always put my username and password in ? I guess I can just have IE on the virtual machine remember my username and password but other than that is there another way to do this ?

Comment: Wouldn't using nat do that?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is nothing built in to accomplish this, but you could probably setup a [proxy on the host](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).